# Parse server hosted on heroku Apple rejection

Tags: ios, heroku, ipv6, parse-server

I have an app using parse server that is hosted on heroku. Apple rejected my app saying that it crashes on IPv6 network. I checked the url to the server on http://ready.chair6.net and it is indeed not compatible. Please help!!! What are possible solutions? parse.com is shutting down in 4 days and I need this migration to take place. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The solution is to debug the crash.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't related to Parse Server, Heroku or Apple requiring IPv6 since many iOS apps are using Parse Server on Heroku successfully. More information here: [More information on "Apple has rejected my application because Heroku does not support IPv6"](https://kb.heroku.com/apple-has-rejected-my-application-because-heroku-does-not-support-ipv6)

> We recommend that you check out how your app manages it's networking and network requests, and then clarify the particular points with Apple if necessary. Note that using domain name-based resolution is almost always preferred over a static IP address, the latter of which being the most common failure we've seen with App Store submissions.

I would investigate how you've configured networking in your application.
If you've signed up for [Cloudflare](http://cloudflare.com), you can have it proxy some of IPv6 traffic to Heroku in the settings panel as a last resort.